# pass a list as a message from server to client SIGNALR

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, signalr

Hi guys im just testing out signalr and i am having too much fun and got a little bit far from my usual skill now my question is can i pass a list to the client here is my code

```
Public Sub Send(message As String, id As String)
        Dim tomessage = OnlineUser.userObj.Where(Function(users) users.userId = id).[Select](Function(users) users.connectionId).SingleOrDefault()
        Dim customers As New List(Of locationslist)

        customers.Add(New locationslist)
        customers((customers.Count - 1)).CITE_NR = message
        customers((customers.Count - 1)).LATITUDE = "114.20"
        customers((customers.Count - 1)).LONGITUDE = "115.20"
        customers((customers.Count - 1)).DATECOMTD = "01/01/2011"
        customers((customers.Count - 1)).CLASSOFF = "MURDER"
        customers((customers.Count - 1)).TIME = "01:20"
        customers((customers.Count - 1)).CASESTAT = "GSLVGED"

        Clients.Client(tomessage).receiveMessage(customers)
    End Sub
```

and on the client i am doing this

```
            usr.client.receiveMessage = function (message) {
                alert("Received from server: " + message.CITE_NR);
            };
```

but unfortunately the message says Received from server: undefined

is this even possible thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Clients.Client(tomessage).receiveMessage(customers), customers is a list. So you should in javascript use message[0].CITE_NR, or use foreach on message (which is messages, not message).

Comment: thank you for the answeri didnt use for each because the list contains only one entry..il try your answer and il let you know about the outcome